Can Noachide apostasy lead to delaying of the Moshiach
Can an individual who committed to being a Noachide, not before any rabbi but to himself and to G-D delay the coming of the Messiah by giving up the Noachide laws and renouncing G-D? What if the individual claims to have had visions in dreams from G-D, will his apostasy delay the Messiah assuming that he is speaking the truth? I am interested especially in the ultra Orthodox perspective like of the likes of Rabbi Yaron Reuven or others with similar mentality.

To be clear - are you mentioning Yaron because he is ultra-orthodox, or because of his style and personality/approach?

Thanks for commenting, I would say both but any ultra Orthodox opinion is welcome.

I will point out that this question sounds a bit like it is coming from a troubled place ("if I want to give up my Noahidism, which I am finding difficult, will the whole world suffer because of me?"). If this is not just a theoretical question but a personal one, please please seek the counsel of an orthodox Rabbi you can speak to directly. Either way, welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Just FYI: For many in the Orthodox world, Yaron Reuven/Yosef Mizrahi are considered to be fringe and outside the pale. Not necessarily the best sources for Torah content.

@Deuteronomy Those in the Orthodox world who don’t consider him fringe, are themselves fringe. So he’s objectively fringe.
